# "Computer guy" upgraded my processor, now screen had flickering color lines

Tags: display, cpu, dell-optiplex

After paying to have my 3.4 single core cpu upgraded to a pentium D 945. Computer is dell Optiplex gx620 and OS is windows XP. Has 4gb ram and the graphics card is geforce gt 430. I know it's not the graphics card because I've tried a Radeon HD 4350 that previously worked as well and when I try the video graphic cards only a black screen with a flickering line in the top right corner shows up. So when I plug the VGA cord into the integrated graphics port the flickering lines show up. This "computer expert" said that he's not responsible and that everything worked when he let the computer go. Also that I "must have done something to it". The power supply is a 550 watt and the motherboard is stock. Help please! I don't want to have to purchase another computer.

Comment: Do you see the flickering lines even in the BIOS setup?

Comment: Can you take a photo of the screen that shows this and put it somewhere, then [edit] a link into your question?

Answer (score 3):

With what you describe, and the fact the problem is the same with two different cards, I would say it's either the monitor or the VGA cable. If you could find/borrow a different one of these, I would start with that.